# UIImageViews to make copies of themselves after being dragged and dropped

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiimageview, drag

I'm trying to get the UIImageViews to make copies of themselves after being dragged and dropped. For example: I have UIImageViews for all the letters of the alphabet.

I hooked them all up using Interface Builder, and they move independently of each other.

I pull an "A" tile (image view) from the alphabet to spell a word.

Currently, if the A is pulled out, I have no other "A" image view to use a second "A" if there are two "A's" in the word to be spelled out.

My weak attempt to create another letter tile:

```
for(UITouch *touch in [event allTouches])
    if ([touch view] == alphabetVowelA) {
        MainSpellingView *alphabetA;
        CGRect alphabetAa = CGRectMake(39, 104, 70, 70);
        alphabetA = [[MainSpellingView alloc] initWithFrame:alphabetAa];
        [alphabetA setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"]];
        [alphabetA setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
        [alphabetA setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [self addSubview:alphabetA];
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];
        alphabetVowelA.center = location;
    }
```

My code: (I only have A, B, and C move) I figure if I can get the first three letters to do what I want, I can make them all do that. So to make things easier to work with and read, you'll notice that only three of them are set up to do anything.

[MainSpellingView.m](http://pastie.org/2444837)

[MainSpellingView.h](http://pastie.org/2444844)

While this code does create another tile using the "a" image in the original location I can't get it to move since it was created after the touchesbegan: and it of course would only work once in creating the new tile.

Ultimately, I want to have a letter tile (UIImageView) regenerate a duplicate of itself in its original location, so that if I need to use another of the same letter, I can simply drag the duplicate that was made once the original "letter tile" (UIImageView) was dragged and dropped down to the "spelling" area.

I'll leave a comment with links to the ViewController code, not that it's really necessary.

Thanks in advance for any help or direction you can give me!

Comment: http://pastie.org/2444854 TheViewController.h

http://pastie.org/2444866 TheViewController.m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the best way to do this is to track the events on the top view that contains all letters as subviews. 
So let's say your letters are all subviews of a view called "contentView". Now if you override the contentView's

```
hitTest:withEvent:
```

by returning nil each time the event touch point intersects one of the draggable letters, you will be able to detect the touch within the contentView (of course if you don't detect the intersection, then call super's hitTest in order to have the correct behavior for other subviews that are not letters).
At this point the contentView's touch methods will manage the letter copy and dragging which is possible as all coordinates will be referenced to this contentView.
Probably contentView's hitTest must return nil in two cases:
- on touch down, when the touch point location intersects one of the letters, then set dragging=YES
- on touch move while dragging==YES you must return always nil
- on touch end while dragging==YES you must return always nil
In all other cases you must call super's (UIView) hitTest to be sure to have proper processing in all other cases.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want more than 3 letters, I would try to think about a generic view (you can distinguish them with `tag`s) and calculating all the other stuff (coordinates etc.) with logic. But this is not your problem (yet).

You mention that you hooked up your `alphabetView`s in IB. It seems that when recreating the new views, you are omitting that step. I.e. the view that is supposed to react to your touches is an `IBOutlet` of your view controller class.

Thus, once the drag is finished, you should assign the new view to the outlet, and things should be working as before.

Comment: How would I go about hooking up a view in IB which I've created programmatically?

Comment: Just assign the new view with to your `@property`.